# TypeError: product.filter is not a function

Tags: filter, typeerror

I know that the value products isn't defined but can anyone fix it. I want search filter init please
the code works while fetching api but it doesn't work while filteration
please help a humble request.
Html code>>

`

```
        </div>
    </div>
```

`

Js Code>>>>>>>>
`(async () => {
const search = document.querySelector('.search');
const main = document.querySelector('.product_container')

```
const url = "https://fakestoreapi.com/products";
const generateProducts = (data) => {
    data.forEach((products) => {
        const main = document.getElementsByClassName('product_container')[0];

        const elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.classList.add('product_card');
        elem.innerHTML = `
            <div class="img">
                <img src="${products.image}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="info">
                <h3>${products.title}</h3>
                <p>${products.description.split(" ").slice(0, 20).join(" ")}</p>
                <button>${products.price}</button>
            </div>
    `
        main.appendChild(elem);
    });
}
const fetchApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    generateProducts(data);
}
fetchApi(url);


const checkProduct = (text, searchText) => {
    return text.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
}
const firstHandler = (event) => {
    const product = fetchApi();

    const searchText = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const filteredProducts = product.filter((item) => {
        return (
            item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        )
    });
    generateProducts(filteredProducts);
}
search.addEventListener('keyup', firstHandler)
```

})();`